# Dynamically create table name with current month HIVE SQL

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am trying to setup an automated script that finishes by creating a new table with that month's name abbrev appended to the table name (e.g. tablename_Jun2022)

I have the following variables with the month/date below:

```
set hivevar:curr_date=trunc(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp())),'MM');
set hivevar:curr_month=date_format(${curr_date},'MMM');
```

However, I'm unable to use the curr_month variable in a table name:

`create table tablename_${curr_month} as...`

since the hivevar isn't storing the end result.

Anyone done this before/know a workaround? Thanks.

Comment: You can use shell script to do this. https://dwgeek.com/hive-dynamic-sql-support-and-alternative.html/

Comment: Thanks @Roshan. Does anyone have an example of the shell script I could use that would allow passing through the month's name? I am new to using bash script-- I'm able to get the month I'm interested in: `date --date="$(date +%Y-%m-1) -1 month" +%b` , however it's not passing through correctly

Comment: It is given in the above link. you can change according to your Needs